# Enforce partitions in sql

Tags: sql

Game night! I have some players:

| Player (primary key) | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Mary Poppins |
| 1 | Peter Pan |
| ... | ... |

Playing various rounds of board games:

| Round (primary key) | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 18:30 |
| 1 | 18:55 |
| ... | ... |

In each round, there are different groups of players coming together to play board games. Each specific game has a game summary of what happened:

| Game Description (primary key) | Summary |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Mary started out strong, but Peter took the lead after ... |
| ... | ... |

How can I combine these by adding/changing SQL tables with the following constraints enforced by the database:

- Each `Player` can join at most one `Game Description` per `Round`
- Each `Game Description` belongs to exactly one round

---

For example this solution:

| Game Description (primary key, foreign key) | Round (foreign key) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |
| ... | ... |

| Player (foreign key) | Game Description (foreign key) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

Would allow storing the relations, but wouldn't prevent one `Player` to be part of multiple `Game Description`s in the same round...